# How to push project from android studio into specific github folder in existing repository?

Tags: android, git, github

Enabling the version control and connecting it to the user account in android studio creates new repository on github for each project and pushes the project to it by default. However, I would like to know if there is a way to setup Android Studio to upload the project to specific folder in already existing repository on github?

Comment: You would have to place your project inside that specific folder locally, commit & then push to GitHub. It's a bit of a workaround unfortunately.

Comment: And all of these I will need to do using GitHub or Git Shell and not Android Studio?

Comment: Yes Git/GitHub I am not sure if you can do it from Android Studio directly as I use the command line commands exclusively.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for help :)

Comment: After commit and push, just open the project again from that directory in Android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have to move all your files to that specific folder and commit & push that folder.

You can not commit & push files **into** something, that is not the idea behind Git. It's mostely about [Version Control](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control)

Answer (score 1):

1. First install git-bash (i won't go through the installation) if not installed.
2. Clone the project on your pc.

   git clone repo-url
3. Now create the required folder (and add files which you want in that folder) inside the repository you cloned on your pc.
4. git add .
5. git commit -m "Message"
6. git push origin master

Comment: `git push origin master` worked for me.